# Tomcat StandardServer issue

Tags: tomcat

I'm reading tomcat source code now and find a piece of code of StandardServer like this:

```
                    // Read a set of characters from the socket

                    int expected = 1024; // Cut off to avoid DoS attack
                    while (expected < shutdown.length()) {
                        if (random == null)
                            random = new Random();
                        expected += (random.nextInt() % 1024);
                    }
                    while (expected > 0) {
                        int ch = -1;
                        try {
                            ch = stream.read();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            log.warn("StandardServer.await: read: ", e);
                            ch = -1;
                        }
                        if (ch < 32)  // Control character or EOF terminates loop
                            break;
                        command.append((char) ch);
                        expected--;
                    }
```

I'm just wondering why it's like that. Why don't we simply write like this:

```
int expected = shutdown.length();
```

Can anybody tell what's the reason behind this?

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html

Comment: Contact tomcat developers?

Answer (score 0):

> Update: as per my comment, see http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-dev&m=99842024409593&w=2 and the next 3 messages in the thread for the explanation of why this code was written the way it was.
>
> The basic gist of it is that when using shutdown.length as
> **expected**, the attacker knows the length of the shutdown command, which is undesirable.
>
> So, **expected** starts at 1024 and then, if
> **expected** < shutdown.length, random integer values get generated and added to **expected** until expected >= shutdown.length.
>
> And all this is so the code can then just read the number of characters from the socket needed to determine if it received a proper shutdown command and
> preventing the attacker of sending x gigabytes of data over the
> socket, causing an OOM exception
>
> The code could probably be improved a bit by preventing **expected** being incremented with negative integer values coming from **(random.nextInt() % 1024)**, by using **random.nextInt(1024)** instead of **(random.nextInt() % 1024)**, but I assume no one ever ran into issues, because no one uses a shutdown command longer than 1024 characters

Have you ever figured this out? As I'm running into the same question.

From what it looks like, they try to prevent a DoS attack by an attacker sending a very, very large message to the socket. They try to do so by not reading more characters from the socket then are needed to determine if the value send to the socket matches the shutdown command string

But I don't understand the logic here either...
For example the code below generates an integer between -1024 and +1024, so why they use that to increase **expected** while **(expected < shutdown.length()** beats me:

> (random.nextInt() % 1024)

Also, shutdown.length() is usually just 8, since the default command string is "shutdown", so the code never goes into the first **while** loop. And would anyone ever override the default shutdown command string to something as long as 1024 characters?

Why **expected** defaults to 1024 instead of just shutdown.length() (or maybe shutdown.length() + 1) is also a mystery to me

I think this code is even buggy in that the code **(random.nextInt() % 1024)** also generates negative integer values, so theoretically, the execution might never get out of that first while loop (if it would ever get into it in the first place)

The code as of the second while-loop, it all makes sense to me though.

Hope you have figured it out and can shed some light on this.

Tia, Paul

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I think it's at least a partial answer, but I did try to comment but stackoverflow won't let me

Comment: ok then, did some more digging and found references to the discussion that lead to this code being implemented back in 2001 :-)

See http://marc.info/?l=tomcat-dev&m=99842024409593&w=2 and the next 3 messages in the thread

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Sorry for not following protocol. I've since updated my answer, I think it now does contain a proper answer. Hope everyone agrees

Not sure if I should remove my previous non-answer. Some of the comments it triggered wouldn't make sense anymore

Comment: Sounds like there's no special reason behind this.